# I have started using telnetlib in recently, what is the difference between tn.read_all and tn.read_very_eager

Tags: python, telnet

I have started using telnet lib in Python recently, what is the difference between tn.read_all and tn.read_very_eager in Python.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation for `read_all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_all):

> Read all data until EOF as bytes; block until connection closed.

From [the documentation for `read_very_eager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_very_eager):

> Read everything that can be without blocking in I/O

So `read_all` reads *all* from the connection, until it's closed. It will block if there's no data to read, but the connection it still open.

The `read_very_eager` will read until *either* connection-closed *or* there's no more data to currently read (where `read_all` would block).

For more information please read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) and other online references and tutorials.